# How to create a WCF service from c# classes generated from an xsd

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, xsd

I have a complex xds file I need to create a WCF SOAP service based on. I have generated the classes using xsd.exe. The resulting classes uses XML serialization.

My challenge is how to use this class to build a service. Please any suggesting a recourse that can guide me will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the c# classes generated when I run `xsd.exe xsdfile.xsd /classes` is all that is needed. I just created a new wcf service and in the operation contract  passed the generated c# object as the parameter and that was it. It worked